# dedup records(window function pandas)

Tags: python, sql, pandas, database, dataframe

Hi I am looking to dedup my records ordered by cancel date so I will only be interested in the most recent record.

sample data

| id | cancel_date | type_of_fruit |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 2021-03-02 | apple |
| 1 | 2021-01-01 | apple |
| 2 | 2021-02-01 | orange |

expected output

| id | cancel_date | type_of_fruit |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 2021-03-02 | apple |
| 2 | 2021-02-01 | orange |

I wrote the SQL way but I have to implement this logic in pandas, please help

```
SELECT 
    * 
FROM 
    (SELECT *, 
            rank() over(partition by id order by cancel_date desc) as rank 
     FROM df 
     ORDER BY id, cancel_date DESC) a 
where rank = 1
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is how you can achieve this.

Below code will convert `cancel_date` column into `datetime` object, because you want to order it using `cancel_date`:

```
#--if cancel_date is a string, then this code will convert to datetime--

import pandas as pd
df['cancel_date']= pd.to_datetime(df['cancel_date'])
```

Next grouping the table on `id` (this is similar to partition in `SQL`), then using `cancel_date` column to be sorted in `descending` order. Below code will achieve the same:

```
df["Rank"] = df.groupby("id")["cancel_date"].rank(method="first", ascending= False)
```

Finally, filtering the data with rank as 1:

```
filtered_df = df[df["Rank"] == 1]
filtered_df.head()
```